# min for each row in a data frame

Tags: r, max, min

I'm try to calculate minimum across multiple columns (row-wise `min`) in a data frame, but the `min` function automatically returns the minimum across the whole of each column rather than for each row separately. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here? Any ideas much appreciated.

```
x <- c(1,2,7)
y <- c(1,5,4)
minIwant <- c(1,2,4)
df <- data.frame(x, y, minIwant)
df$minIget <- min(df$x,df$y)
df
  x y minIwant minIget
1 1 1        1       1
2 2 5        2       1
3 7 4        4       1
```

Comment: @RichScriven's is less intuitive (to me) but much faster, for anyone who's in optimization mode.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `apply` to go through each row

```
apply(df, 1, FUN = min)
```

Where `1` means to apply `FUN` to each row of df, `2` would mean to apply `FUN` to columns.

To remove missing values, use:

```
apply(df, 1, FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: excellent thanks. And if I have a large data frame how do I specify which columns of applying the FUN too?

Comment: The same way you would normally subset by column, e.g. `apply(df[, c(1, 3, 5)], ...)`.

Comment: what does this 1 actually mean??

Comment: @user9191983 as I said, 1 means to apply to each row. If you want to apply to columns you would use 2!

Comment: But this does not work with NAs. How can I get this working with na.rm = TRUE?

Comment: @JASC: `apply(df, 1, FUN=min, na.rm=TRUE)` should work

Answer (score 19):

We could use `pmin`, which finds the parallel minima of sets of values.  Since our `df` is technically a list, we will need to run it via `do.call`.

```
df$min <- do.call(pmin, df)
```

which gives

```
df
#   x y min
# 1 1 1   1
# 2 2 5   2
# 3 7 4   4
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 7), y = c(1, 5, 4))
```

Furthermore, if `na.rm = TRUE` is needed, you can do

```
df$min <- do.call(pmin, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This is good, but does not work with NAs. How can I get this working with na.rm = TRUE?

Comment: @JASC - You can do `do.call(pmin, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))`.  See `help(do.call)` for info on how to use a list in the `args` argument.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add on how you can also do this with dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

x<-c(1,2,7)
y<-c(1,5,4)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minIget = min(x, y))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    x     y   minIget
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1    1.    1.      1.
2    2.    5.      2.
3    7.    4.      4.
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(minIget = pmin(x, y))` is probably more performant.

Comment: The difference between dplyr's `rowwise()` and `pmin()` was significant in my application:  `rowwise()` ran 21.5 seconds and `pmin()` ran 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

We could also use `rowMins` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
df$minIwant <- rowMins(as.matrix(df))
```