# create new column (with outcome min or NA) from multiple selected columns

Tags: r, apply, min, sapply, inf

My data has many columns and subjects, but to illustrate it simpler, lets say I have 7 subjects with 3 variables/columns called x1, x2 and x3 (values range from 1 to 3 and NAs).  In the analysis that I want it is important I actually call the columns I want to use (since I cannot just use the whole dataframe in my analysis because there are more variables/columns there)

```
>data <- data.frame(‘id’=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), ‘x1’=c(1,2,2,NA,3,3,1), ‘x2’=c(NA,3,1,NA,2,3,2), ‘x3’=c(NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,1)
    id  x1  x2  x3
    1   1   NA  NA
    2   2   3   2
    3   2   1   NA
    4   NA  NA  NA
    5   3   2   NA
    6   3   3   NA
    7   1   2   1
```

The class of x1 x2 and x3 are numeric.
Out of that, I want to create a variable/column called ‘x4’ that:
- gives me the lowest number of row x1, x2 and x3.

-If there is an NA in a row of x1,x2,x3, the NA shall be ignored.

-If they are however ALL NAs, I would want the outcome to be NA. (NOT Inf, which is what it does with my code now)

-If there are two lowest numbers that are the same, just display any one of those two. So like this:

```
>data <- data.frame(‘id’=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), ‘x1’=c(1,2,2,NA,3,3,1), ‘x2’=c(NA,3,1,NA,2,3,2), ‘x3’=c(NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,1), ‘x4’=c(1,2,1,NA,2,3,1)
    id  x1  x2  x3  x4
    1   1   NA  NA  1
    2   2   3   2   2
    3   2   1   NA  1
    4   NA  NA  NA  NA  
    5   3   2   NA  2
    6   3   3   NA  3
    7   1   2   1   1
```

I managed to find a very similar question, and I can mostly make it work: [min for each row with dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683234/min-for-each-row-with-dataframe-in-r)

data$x4 <- apply(data[, c("x1","x2","x3")],1, FUN=min, na.rm = TRUE)

the problem I have now is that in case of all NAs (so id number 4), my outcome is not NA, but it is 'Inf'.

**Question 1**:How can I make it so it becomes an NA instead of Inf? I can of course do that afterwards like this:

is.na(data$x4) <- sapply(data$x4, is.infinite)

But I wonder if there is a nice way to do that already with/inside the previous code?

Also, rather then using sapply and the inside FUNction min, I would also like to try to make it work with code in a way like below: **Question 2:** is using this other code below possible?

data$x4 <- min(data[, c("x1","x2","x3")],1 , na.rm = TRUE)

for this x4 gets the outcome '1' everytime. I guess it just shows the lowest number (1) of the whole column? I dont understand why. I am already using ',1' but doesnt help.

I hope somebody can help me(r and stackoverflow newbie) out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `pmin` function which returns the (regular or parallel) minima of the input values. Below are two approaches using pmin:

```
df$minIget <- do.call(pmin, c(df[,-1], na.rm = TRUE)) # Approch1: using do.call

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(minIget = pmin(x1, x2,x3,na.rm = T))# Approch2: using tidyverse.
```

output:

```
 A tibble: 7 x 5
# Rowwise: 
     id    x1    x2    x3 minIget
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1    NA    NA       1
2     2     2     3     2       2
3     3     2     1    NA       1
4     4    NA    NA    NA      NA
5     5     3     2     3       2
6     6     3     3    NA       3
7     7     1     2     1       1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! About approach 1. I get the error incorrect number of dimensions. I tried these codes based on yours:         `df$minIget <- do.call(pmin, c("x1","x2","x3"[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))`                 I also tried this one and got the same error:                                   `df$minIget <- do.call(pmin, c(data$x1,data$x2, data$x3 [,-1], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @RelcioR you are referring columns wrongly. The selection of variables can be done either by index or by column name. in Approach 1. as per my answer I have passed using the index, df[,-1] refers to all columns except the last one. In approach 2 I have used column names. [Refer](https://dzone.com/articles/learn-r-how-extract-rows) . So you have to run it as it's given in my answer it will run properly

Comment: thank you for getting back to me and helping me understand it:) Also that link about referring is very useful for me (im still a beginner). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, That's what for SO is, to learn by helping each other.  Also, It's best practice for a question poster to upvote and select an answer among all solutions if his query has been answered by other SO members.  Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . You can upvote multiple answers but selected answers can be one only, where you will click tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if all are `NA` before you call `min` like:

```
apply(data[, c("x1","x2","x3")], 1, function(x)
  if(all(is.na(x))) NA else min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
#[1]  1  2  1 NA  2  3  1
```

`min(data[, c("x1","x2","x3")],1 , na.rm = TRUE)` gives you the minimum of `1` and `data[, c("x1","x2","x3")]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I understand your answer for question 1, thanks!, but for question 2, I do not see an improved version of my code? I think you used the same? So what I think my code does is looks at the minimum value of the whole column, but I want it too look at the minium value per row. I'm having trouble to change that in my code.  P.S. , sorry for my late reply

Comment: Whit this it's possible to get the min for one row. E.g. for row1 `min(data[1, c("x1","x2","x3")], na.rm = TRUE)` or for row2 `min(data[2, c("x1","x2","x3")], na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thansk for your reply! yes that works, but could the code be in such a way that is automaticlly does this for all seven rows and creates my desired column x4?  I tried `min(data[1:7, c("x1","x2","x3")], na.rm = TRUE)` , but then it just gives the same min value of one of the seven rows. So my outcome is again all 1 1 1 1 1 1 1.

Comment: In this case use `apply` to go over each row.